# PHP oracle database connection string

Tags: php, oracle

I had a weird experience connecting to oracle database using PHP.

Firstly, from the past 3 years I am connecting to oracle using easy connection string. I had the code on my windows 7 machine.

A week ago I got a new windows 7 machine and when I tried to connect to oracle. It gave me the following error

**ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified**

Later I figured out oci_connect is only accepting SID and not the easy connect string.

Now I didn't understand why is it behaving weirdly in my new machine. Can anyone please help me to figure out if it is some problem with windows software settings?

Thanks,
Sri

Comment: does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252286/ora-12154-tnscould-not-resolve-the-connect-identifier-specified ?

Comment: 1. Have you enable oci8 extantions in your wamp....or just use phpinfo() to check this

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you enable oci8 extantions in your wamp....or just use phpinfo() to check this
2. If it is working fine then on which server you are connection database
       If it is Local then you need to Start services of Oracle from your machine
   which are as mention in my snap
   [image]
3. also you need to start your database service which you want tot connect to your database.